# Animated Interactive plots in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter, seaborn

I have a df that contains some data that I interactively filter with ipywidgets. This is the code that filters the df:

```
@interact_manual(channel=channel_widget,currency=currency_widget,
                 use_cumulative=cumulative_widget)
def filter_df_1(channel, currency, use_cumulative):
    filtered1 = df[(df['SALES CHANNEL'].isin(channel)) & 
                         (df['CURRENCY']==currency)]
    return filtered1
```

This code works fine and produces the expected output.

After the data is filtered, I wish two plot two KDE Lines on the same plot (Im using seaborn but don't really mind any plotting library as long as I can get the animation to work properly) and then animate the plot month by month, drawing two lines for each month on the same figure and erasing the previous month's lines. Here is the unworking code:

```
def animate_kde():
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.xlim(0,17500)
    plt.xlabel('Price')
    plt.ylabel('Density')
    month_list = ['','January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
                  'August','September','October','Novemer','December']
    plt.title('Price Density {}'.format(month_list[current_date]))

    data = filter_df_1(channel_widget.value,currency_widget.value,cumulative_widget.value)
    data = data[data['MONTH']==current_date]
    base = data.groupby('FAMILY')[' PRICE/UNIT (EGP) '].mean().rename('BASE')
    ax1 = sns.kdeplot(base)
    ax2 = sns.kdeplot(data[' PRICE/UNIT (EGP) '])

    def init():
        plt.cla()
        ax1 = sns.kdeplot(base)
        ax2 = sns.kdeplot(data[' PRICE/UNIT (EGP) '])

    def animate(i):
        plt.cla()
        current_date=i
        ax1 = sns.kdeplot(base)
        ax2 = sns.kdeplot(data[' PRICE/UNIT (EGP) '])

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, 
                                   frames=range(0,12), interval=1000)

    rc('animation',html='jshtml')

    HTML(anim.to_jshtml())


animate_kde()
```

When run, this code just produces a static image that doesn't animate and doesn't observe changes in the filtration of the df through interacting with the widgets.

Like this:

[image: Plot]

I am not trained as a programmer so I know I am probably making a bunch of mistakes in my code.

The desired output is an animated plot that observes the filtration of the df through the interactive widgets.

Comment: I have a repository [here](https://github.com/fomightez/animated_matplotlib-binder) that you can click on the `launch binder` badge to launch an active session with some animated plots and links to other resources. Something there might help on you animation side. It would probably help others help you, if you maybe made a repo like that with your code and dummy or obfuscated data (assuming you'd rather not publicly share it). I'd also suggest maybe just doing the filtering as a step in another cell and get the animated plot working with the correct data first given the title of your post.

Comment: There is an earlier version of my code that works fine for a pre-filtered dataframe. It is when I try filtering & animation in the same cell that it stops working.
Will check out your repo.